# How to deserialize a file back to the original class object

Tags: java, android, file-io, deserialization

I created a class and I periodically save objects of this class to internal storage using Serializable. When I want to retrieve these objects, I use this approach:

```
for(File i: getFilesDir().listFiles()){
    //Skipped enclosing try-catch block
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(i.getName());
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        SingleWallet theObjectWeWant = ois.readObject();
             }
```

This results in a compile-time error (Incompatible types). How do I get my class back from the `object` returned from `ois.readObject()`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You read a tutorial on serialization. Those typically cover the de-serialization part as well. And they also explain how to properly serialize objects. For example by calling close only once, on the correct stream.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The mistake I made was failing to cast my newly gotten object to my intended class.

Changing

```
SingleWallet theObjectWeWant = ois.readObject();
```

to

```
SingleWallet theObjectWeWant = (SingleWallet) ois.readObject();
```

made the difference.

Basically, I should have casted from object to SingleWallet.

I hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: In other words there was a *compiler error* that you failed to mention in your question when you completely rewrote it, and before as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Even when I use listFiles() to get all the files in the directory, they are represented as files, not Card Objects.

That's because they *are* files, not objects.

Comment: I have edited the question to improve quality and coherency... I have also added an exact answer below. Thanks a lot for the help.