# How to store dates in listview items?

Tags: java, android, date, listview

So I want to add date of the day it was entered with every item in listview. Problem is I dont know how to store dates, date keeps updating to current day even though item was entered yesterday or a week before.

This is the code for date

```
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd" + " MMM");
    String month_name = month_date.format(cal.getTime());
```

This is the code for date entered in listview item

```
  while ((iterator2.hasNext() )) {
        String add = iterator2.next();
        conCat2.add("Added : " + add + "    "+ month_name);


    }
```

Comment: It always be, are you store the date on database or SharedPreferences?

Comment: You never *store* dates using this code. And question about storing something in general on Android is too broad for proper answer.

Comment: yes it is broad that's why I'm asking specifically. I want to store dates of day the items were entered. Can you help?\

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now supplanted the java.time classes. For older Android, see the ThreeTen-Backport and ThreeTenABP projects.

## `MonthDay` class

Use the `MonthDay` class for a date without a year. Note that unlike the legacy classes, java.time uses sane month numbering, 1-12 for January to December.

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.of( 1 , 23 ) ;
```

Or, using the `Month` enum.

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.of( Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
```

## `LocalDate`

If you meant an entire date with year, use `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2017 , 1 , 23 ) ;
```

Comment: This is just formatting right? I want  to display the dates of the day the items were entered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is majorly storage. You could store the date somewhere so you can fetch at your own convenience.. Your options are broad actually. You can achieve this by:

- Using the concept of object oriented programming and Serializable, you can create a model class with set and get methods for your date, create objects for each item ever inputted and then store the object to device memory using serializable. You can then fetch when you're loading your listview, this way your date will always be correct. Set once and the value of the date will never change. To learn how to store data to device memory using Serializable, read the accepted answer on this question: [Object serialization in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44198259/object-serialization-in-java][])
- You can save in an online database (e.g Firebase) and then fetch when you need it. I'd advise you take tutorials on the use of Firebase. This link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/ will give you a headstart.
- Store in some other database.